# Setting up a PC to switch on automatically at a specific time via Bios " setup task remotely "

Tags: windows, bios, automation

In regards to the following I was looking to setup some Windows 10 computers in my office office to automatically switch on each morning in case they were switched off the day before by our users when they were working remotely from home.

I know this can be done in the bios settings manually by pressing F2 on bootup if I was to be in the office but my question was if there was a way possible to get this done remotely, either by PowerShell scripts or group policy whilst the PC's are switched on and if someone could please point me in the right direction if this is something simple to administer ?

We are currently using dell OptiPlex 7010's and we do have the ability to Wake on Lan etc on our network but we would have liked to automate this if possible and I was thinking setting this in the bios may be the best option, unless someone does have a better idea?

Please let me know if anyone does have any ideas or if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Waking up a Windows computer that was shutdown, and not through the BIOS,
can be done using the task scheduler, as follows.

**Allow automatic turn on/off**

- Open *Power Options > Change when the computer sleeps*
- Click "Change advanced power settings"
- Under *Sleep > Allow wake-up timers* set all to "Enable"

**Schedule Auto-Start with Task Scheduler**

- Run the *Task Scheduler*
- Click "Task Scheduler Library"
- Click "Create task"
- Enter name and description and tick "Run whether user is logged on or not"
  and also "Run with highest privileges"
- On the Triggers tab, click New
- Set the frequency and time for automatically turning on the computer,
  for example daily at 11:42 am
- In the action tab, click New and type a name for the action
- In the Conditions tab, check "Wake the computer to run this task"
- Click OK and exit the Task Scheduler.

For a detailed description with screenshots see the article
[How to Set Windows 10 Computer to Auto-Start on a Schedule](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/how-to-set-windows-10-computer-to-auto-start-on-a-schedule.html).